# Symlink two dirs in perl

Tags: perl

I have below code for symlink two dirs..

```
my $Directory = "/data/backups/";
my $symLinkDirectory = "newdisk/data/backups/";

opendir ( DIR, $Directory ) || die "Error in opening directory $Directory\n";
while( ( $fileName = readdir(DIR))){
    my $filePath = "$Directory"."$fileName";
    symlink("$filePath","$symLinkDirectory"."$fileName");
}

closedir(DIR);
```

This works fine when i run it locally.. but when i combined  this to another script this give an error..

```
Global symbol "$fileName" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $fileName"?) at
```

Any idea why this happen ? why works in local and not when combined?

Comment: As the error message says, you should have `while (my $filename = readdir(DIR))`.  What do you mean by "_combined this to another script_" -- how do you "_combine_" them?

Comment: actually not a combine.. im adding this to a existing script.

Comment: but my concern why it works if i run only above script and gives this error when i run my script which is included this ?

Comment: A guess: In this script you don't have `use strict;` so a variable introduced as `$fileName` (no `my`) is OK.  But the other script has `use strict;` so all variables have to be declared with `my`, so when you add this code to that script the undeclared `$fileName` now draws that error message.  (Btw, my recommendation: _always_ have `use strict;` and `use warnings;` at the beginning of every script.)

Comment: yes!!!! LIFE SAVIOR!!! thanks

Comment: maybe in future someone will get same question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `$fileName` is not declared. In the absence of `strict` mode, it implicitly becomes a global variable.

However, your other script probably does `use strict;` (as it should), so undeclared variables are an error. The fix is (as the error message suggests) to make it a local variable with `my`:

```
while( ( my $fileName = readdir(DIR))){
```

---

By the way, `DIR` is also effectively global in your code. There's no reason for that:

```
opendir(my $dh, $Directory) or die "$0: error in opening directory $Directory: $!\n";
while (my $fileName = readdir($dh)) {
```

You can use a normal variable instead of a bareword handle. Also, the error message should include `$0` (the name of your script) and `$!` (the reason for the error).

Also, you probably shouldn't try to symlink `.` and `..`:

```
    next if $fileName eq '.' || $fileName eq '..';
```

As for `my $filePath = "$Directory"."$fileName"`, you should either use plain concatenation or string interpolation:

```
    my $filePath = $Directory . $fileName;
    # -or-
    my $filePath = "$Directory$fileName";
```

There's no need to quote `"$variables"` on their own. This isn't a shell script.

`symlink` can fail. Your code should probably check for that:

```
    symlink($filePath, $symLinkDirectory . $fileName) or warn "$0: can't symlink $filePath to $symLinkDirectory$fileName: $!\n";
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation. of course ill update the script.